# Trying to Fit Image Grid into one page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am stuck trying to fit my image grid into one page. One page means visible page or just adjusting the container of the grid so I can fit it on the screen accordingly.

Target Website: [test.ebdesigns.us](http://test.ebdesigns.us)

Target Grid Starts With:

```html
<aside id="listify_widget_taxonomy_image_grid-6" class="home-widget listify_widget_taxonomy_image_grid">
  <div class="home-widget-section-title">
    <h2 class="home-widget-title">Our Popular Categories</h2>
    <h2 class="home-widget-description">Our Popular Categories</h2>
  </div>
```

I am trying to display it all on one page. When I try to set the width of the individual grids to `height: 150px` nothing happens.

Could you please help me fit the grid in one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on that website it isn't the height that adjusts the grid size, but the padding. Try `.entry-cover.has-image{padding:50px;}` or something like that. I tried it in the dev tools and you'll also probably want to adjust your font size to like 20px or something.

Comment: Thanks... I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey one more quick question. I cannot seem to change the font of the image grid. The only way I can change it is if I select the generic div element.